# Can you connect 4 wired xbox 360 controllers to one pc?

Tags: controllers, windows

I would like to play some steam games I bought with 3 other people. These are games much more suited to a controller however, and I only own two PS4 controllers.

My question is, If I were to buy enough wired Xbox 360 controllers for everyone to use, would they all be able to be plugged in and recognized by a single computer? I have read in other questions that wireless controllers can support up to 4, but I wanted to be sure that the wired ones can do the same before I made the purchase.

As a side note, does anyone have any experience using both ps4 and wired 360 controllers in the same game? If I were using software like DS4Windows would they all just be recognized as 360 controllers or are they incompatible in the same game/computer. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly may want to ask that last question as a separate question

Comment: I don't know about wired 360 controllers, but I've successfully had two Xbox 360 wireless controllers, one PS3 controller using USB, and one PS4 controller using USB connected simultaneously for a 4-player couch co-op game on Steam. Every game is different though potentially, depends how the game is coded, in theory it should work though.

Comment: 4 wireless is easy as pie indeed with a wireless receiver. I would imagine 4 wired would work as well, assuming you have enough USB ports for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can connect them. As long as the game supports four joystick devices you should be able to play with all four controllers. You can also connect a mix of wired and wireless. The wireless receiver simply acts like a USB hub for the controllers.

As for your DS4Windows question, that would be a seperate issue.